# Upload multiple files with single input Asp Mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I want to upload multiple files including Word Documents, Pdf and Images.
I need to use a single input for files because we don't know how many files will be uploaded.

My code is this but I have problem that I can't send files to server side.

Controller Code :

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Content")] Message message, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         // Object save logic
         SaveFiles(message,files);
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
     return View(message);
}
```

Part of view code :

```
<form name="registration"  action="">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Content" >Content:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control compose_content" rows="5" id="Content" name="content"></textarea>

            <div class="fileupload">
                      Attachment :  

                    <input id="files" name="files" type="file" multiple />
            </div>
        </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default compose_btn" >Send Message</button>
</form>
```

I don't have problem with saving files and saving the object.
only problem :
files list is null.

Comment: Show your `<form>` element

Comment: I added that in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I order to upload files, your form needs to include the `enctype= multipart/form-data` attribute.

```
<form name="registration"  action="" enctype= "multipart/form-data">
```

or better

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(actionName, controllerName, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype= "multipart/form-data" }))
```

and I strongly recommend you pass a model to the view and use the strongly typed `HtmlHelper` methods to create your html for the properties of your model.